# What is the right way to put filter on the column having a data type of 'DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND'?

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

I am working on a project where I am looking to fetch everything for the month of May2023 from the informix database. My query works but it stops fetching the data after 1757th record where it should give me all 1890 records for the month.
After reaching to the 1757th record it throws an error;

Quest.Toad.NativeOdbc.NativeOdbcException
[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Inexact character conversion during translation.

Query I am using;

`SELECT  col1   , col2   , col3   , col4  , col5 FROM allyear  WHERE (col5 BETWEEN '2023-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-05-31 23:59:59')`

Data Type for Col5 - YEAR TO SECOND

Comment: As a general rule it is safer to use a combination of `>=` with `<` instead of "between" i.e. `where col5 >= '2023-05-01' and col5 < '2023-06-01'` this way no matter what the time precision of the data is you can be assured of getting every item for the wanted period.  What you might also need is explicit conversion of the date literals to a datetime value e.g.  `where col5 >= to_date('2023-05-01' ,'%Y-%m-%d')`  **nb** you do not need to specify all time units down to second, or lower, if you stick to the `>=` and `<` method

Comment: The error is almost certainly not related to the DATETIME values but rather to some data in one of the other columns.  Try dropping each of the CHAR columns from `col1` … `col4` in turn, and see whether the query runs to completion.  Consider running `oncheck` on the table to validate the data.